# Error in starting activity from doInBackground()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new to android development.
I want to perform some db operations and then, want to start a new activity. I have written AsyncTask code below.

I am getting error on startActivity call. Please help me out.

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Context mainContext;

    public AsyncTaskRunner(Context mainContext){
        this.mainContext=mainContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        publishProgress("Sleeping..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
        try {
            sql.updateRelations();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
        return "";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        InitActivity.progress.dismiss();
        Intent intent = new Intent(mainContext, MainActivity.class);
        if(mainContext!=null){
            mainContext.startActivity(intent);
            ((Activity)mainContext).finish();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        InitActivity.progress.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Always be specific about the error.  What is the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

If your async task is an inner class of your activity then do the below

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, MainActivity.class);
    if(mainContext!=null){
        mainContext.startActivity(intent);
        ((Activity)mainContext).finish();
    }
```

Else if your async task is a separate class then try the below

```
        Intent intent = new Intent((YourActivityName)mainContext, MainActivity.class);
    if(mainContext!=null){
        mainContext.startActivity(intent);
        ((Activity)mainContext).finish();
    }
```

If it doesn't work please post your logs so i can be of better help.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am using inner class. I tried these both. They are working on android studio as well as on physical devices. But, on some devices, app is getting crashed at this point. The issue is happeing in mobile, that is why I am unable to have a log.

Comment: Connect your mobile and see logs through logcat. Have a look at the link on how to do this. http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html#RunningOnDeviceStudio